# Не устанавливается SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, flask-sqlalchemy

При попытке установки *Flask-SQLAlchemy* в *Windows*
выдает ошибку:

```
Running setup.py install for SQLAlchemy ... error

Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\users\анатолий\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\lib\site-
packages\pip\compat\__init__.py", line 73, in console_to_str
return s.decode(sys.__stdout__.encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 60: 
invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: как устанавливали?

Comment: Путь не должен содержать кириллических символов. Или переименуйте профиль или установите Python куда-нибудь в другое место.

Comment: Переименовал папку профиля на латиницу. Теперь Python глючит, почему-то видит старые пути(где папка на кириллице). Даже после переустановки самого Pythona, с последующей чисткой компа, при новой установке Python пишет старый путь? Засада какая-то.